# Android GoogleMap is location available

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an instance of `GoogleMap` and it works fine. How can I find out if it can retrieve current location? 
I have a method that identifies if location is available, but it returns true even if I set phone to airplane mode, but my location isn't updated. Is there any way to detect if GoogleMap can access my location and what should be the course of action to direct user to enable network?

Here is my code to access network:

```
public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context)
{
    LocationManager lm = null;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (lm != null)
    {    gpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        networkEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    if(!gpsEnabled && !networkEnabled){
        DevLog.e("NETWORK NOT AVAILABLE");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {

        DevLog.e("NETWORK IS AVAILABLE", gpsEnabled, networkEnabled);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it with disabled GPS on your device and active airplane mode.

Comment: DevLog.e("NETWORK IS AVAILABLE", gpsEnabled, networkEnabled);
This line says that network is available too but it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

The think you need to understand is that GPS differs from network so even though you put your mobile in airplane mode the GPS will work and brings you the location.

Try to change your code as follows

```
if (lm != null){
    gpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
if(gpsEnabled && isNetworkAvailable()){
    DevLog.e("NETWORK IS AVAILABLE", gpsEnabled, networkEnabled);
    return true;
} else if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
    DevLog.e("NETWORK NOT AVAILABLE");
    return false;
} else if(!gpsEnabled ){
    DevLog.e("GPS NOT AVAILABLE");
    return false;
} else{
    DevLog.e("GPS & NETWORK ARE NOT AVAILABLE");
    return false;
}



private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;   
}
```

This will work for you
check it by changing your phone to airplane mode....!

Comment: Logs say that they both are available even if i put phone in airplane mode, close all possible network

Comment: Don't use LocationManager to get Network status it is only for GPS(Location).  Use Connectivity Manager.

Check the answer i've edited.

Answer (score -1):

The Google Maps API has location stuff, you can do it using that, for example:

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
        if(mMap != null){
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
        }
    }
};
```

and then set the listener for the map:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

This will get called when the map first finds the location.

No need for LocationService or LocationManager at all.

Comment: The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener.html) mention, that the interface OnMyLocationChangeListener is deprecated. Hence it should not be used anymore.

Comment: I am suprised it is depricated. What should I use instead of it? And it doesn't help me to understand if I can retrieve current location.